# LuaLaTeX luaotfload: LuaTeX error: stack overflow (too many arguments)

Tags: luatex, luaotfload

As I was trying to compile a document with LuaLaTex, which used to compile well before, lualatex finished on an error:

```
luaotfload | db : Font names database not found, generating new one.
luaotfload | db : This can take several minutes; please be patient.
luaotfload | db : Updating the font names database.
luaotfload | db : Blacklisting 8 files and directories.
luaotfload | db : Whitelisting 0 files.
luaotfload | db : Scanning TEXMF and OS fonts...
luaotfload | db : Scanned 2486 files, 890 new.
luaotfload | db : Scanning OS fonts...
luaotfload | db : Searching in static system directories...
! LuaTeX error ...texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-database.lua:2383:
 stack overflow (too many arguments).
<to be read again> 
relax 
l.100 \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont

?
```

From this thread [Compilation error with LuaLaTeX (luaotfload- database.lua)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152238/compilation-error-with-lualatex-luaotfload-database-lua), though now it shouldn't be the same problem, I ran the following commands but still got exactly the same error:

```
$ luaotfload-tool --cache=purge
$ luaotfload-tool -u
luaotfload | db : Font names database not found, generating new one.
luaotfload | db : This can take several minutes; please be patient.
...texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-database.lua:2383: stack overflow (too many arguments)
```

Also, I thought maybe there's still the same old buggy version on my distro, like in the thread, so I tried to:

```
$ sudo tlmgr restore luaotfload 31286[sudo] password for nico: 
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
cannot setup TLPDB in /home/nico/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 5336.
```

So, what can I do?

If this may be useful:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ometeotl 3.16.0-29-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 16 20:54:13 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lualatex --version
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2013121407  (TeX Live 2013/dev/Debian) (rev 4627)

$ luaotfload-tool --version    
[...]    
luaotfload-tool version "2.4-3"
revision "bd307a8fe8047d322317037c1a832720c236fb48"
database version "2.41"
Lua interpreter: stock; version "Lua 5.2"
Luatex SVN revision 4627
Luatex version 0.76.0
```

Comment: Perhaps this bug report is related: https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/275

Comment: Well, Ulrike, your link led me back
[there](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250334/luaotfload-font-names-database-creation-crashes/250759?noredirect=1). I tried this mv /etc/fonts/fonts.conf /etc/fonts/tmprm-fonts.conf and the error doesn't show up. It compiles fine but a font I wanted to use has been replaced by another one, so I don't know if the problem is exactly solved. It's a workaround that creates another problem - less annoying though.

Comment: Without and example and the log-file it is impossible to tell you something about your font problem. Beside this: your luatex and luaotfload-tool is rather old. Perhaps you should consider to install texlive 2015.

Comment: Yes, well I don't know how the font problem is related to the first problem in this thread. Now I managed to use the font I want, but I don't know exactly why the previous way of doing it doesn't work anymore. But I guess this is an entirely different question (moreover it involves beamer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as stated in the comments, this thread:
[luaotfload font names database creation crashes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250334/luaotfload-font-names-database-creation-crashes/250759?noredirect=1)

led me to do this:

```
$ mv /etc/fonts/fonts.conf /etc/fonts/tmprm-fonts.conf
```

Then the compilation works to the end:

```
$ lualatex beamer_test.tex
.
.
.
```

After that, I renamed the file as it was before:

```
$ mv /etc/fonts/tmprm-fonts.conf /etc/fonts/fonts.conf
```

And any further compilation does work now.
I just had to add a \fontspec{Ubuntu} in each new frame (this document uses beamer) in order to have this font used (although before, \setsansfont{Ubuntu} was enough, at the beginning of the document).